# Videos won't upload

Tags: php, video, upload

I'm trying to upload some videos using PHP.
But I can't get them into any folder.
I don't get errors, so I don't know where to start.

My code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['files']))
    {
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "upload/{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}");
        }
     }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Uploading videos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" min="1" max="9999" />
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to upload, .webm, .ogv and .mp4
The files aren't that big, they're just 5MB or something.
First I got this error in Apache log: POST Content-Length of 15236606 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608. So I changed that limit from 8MB to 80MB and now that error is gone, but the files aren't uploaded yet. And there are no errors anymore.
When I try to send some images, I get them. Probably there is something not handled correctly. But I don't know what.

Thanks in advance for the help ;)

Bjorn

Comment: Check if `move_uploaded_file` is returning false when you call it and make sure you don't suppress warnings.
Also, a `print_r($_FILES['files']);` in the if block couldn't hurt.  You'd rather get too much info than not enough.

Comment: How is that an HTML5 uploader? :S

Comment: @jValdron I've changed those to something high as well. ;)
+GigaWatt I've did that, the only thing I can see what's going bad is that the filetype is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to up the following settings:

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
memory_limit
```

Also `set_time_limit` to something high as well.

Comment: I forgot the upload_max_filesize ;) Thanks

Comment: saved my day!
as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280825/mp3-mp4-php-upload-doesnt-work), the error messages aren't very clear sometimes.