# MP3 / MP4 PHP upload doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, wamp

I really despair at this problem. I already found some other threads that consider about this problem, but I don't found a solution for me.

I want to upload a mp3 / mp4 file. But with my current solution only pictures are being uploaded.

This question is only about the core functionality of upload a mp3 / mp4 file - I conscious exclude any security checks or kind of this.

PHP:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name']))
{
    echo "Successfully Uploaded Images";
}
else
{
    echo "Error while uploading";
}
```

JS:

```
file = this.files[i];

if (window.FileReader) {
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        //showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
if (formdata) {
    formdata.append("file", file);
}

if (formdata) 
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(res) 
        {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**
I already set the upload_max_filesize to 32 MB.

I got this response from the server:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\musicplayer_www\public_html\4_upload\upload.php on line 3
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0022  134720  {main}( )   ..\upload.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\musicplayer_www\public_html\4_upload\upload.php on line 3
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0022  134720  {main}( )   ..\upload.php:0
```

**EDIT 2:**
HTML Form:

```
<div id="main">
     <h1>1. upload track to ftp</h1>
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
     <input type="file" name="images" id="images" multiple/>

     <button type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-default">Upload Files!</button>
     </form>

     <div id="response"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT 3:**
In reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402139/videos-wont-upload), there some more limits we have to consider:

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
memory_limit
```

So the thought of bluesky is in the right direction.

Comment: please show code in line 3 of upload.php

Comment: line 3 is the first line of the php code I've inserted

Comment: can you show the html form code?

Comment: Error Shows that your file didn't reached to your server. You have to append your file with your post data. Only then it could work.

Comment: if I look what is inside variable file - it shows me exactly the file information the respective file provide. So there should be something between the javascript and php right? And where is the difference between pictures & mp3? Pictures works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your mp3,mp4 file too large, you can check `Maximum allowed size for uploaded file` in php.ini, default you can upload file with 2Mb, change `upload_max_filesize` and restart your server

Comment: I already set this to a limit of 32mb. Sorry, I've forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});

jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: He cannot read your '#file' tag...:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

Comment: "#file" is id not a tag. give images in that place